# Typescript not inferring correctly? (infer one object of a type from the union of objects in terms of a field being a concatenated string)

Tags: typescript

How can I get typescript to infer within the scope of the if statement that d contains a, in the following snippet?

```
  type Data<NS extends string> = { type: `${NS}/1`; a: string } | { type: `${NS}/2`; b: string };
  const foo = <NS extends string>(name: NS, d: Data<NS>): void => {
    if (d.type === (`${name}/1` as const)) {
      // Property 'a' does not exist on type 'Data<NS>'. Property 'a' does not        _exist on type '{ type: `${NS}/2`; b: string; }'.
      d.a;
    }
  };
```

The above snippet is analogously to the below, which does infer correctly, but does not contain concatenated string constants (which is what I require):

```
type Data<NS extends string> = { type: `1`; a: string } | { type: `2`; b: string }
const foo = <NS extends string>(name: NS, d: Data<NS>): void => { 
  if (d.type === (`1` as const)) {
    d.a;
  } 
}
```